# Why does GitHub Pages change the format of my button?

Tags: html, css, github-pages, mailchimp

I am trying to host a website I made with GitHub Pages. I included a button that takes the user to a MailChimp emailing list signup form. Everything looks the way I want it to (centred and rounded) when I open my HTML file locally. When viewing on GitHub Pages, however, the button doesn't seem to have referenced the CSS file properly and also floats to the left of the screen.

https://gyazo.com/e0135aabf17c1bff674ef6f0b24cf742

https://gyazo.com/2d21fe34c9a9024917b088936f58e257

The HTML:

```
<!-- MailChimp -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="https://facebook.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=f10d5f8c984b9e327a2ca8084&amp;id=921f2a892d" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
                <input type="text" name="b_f10d5f8c984b9e327a2ca8084_921f2a892d" tabindex="-1" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
                <input type="submit" value="Sign up for our mailing list" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button btn btn-outline-white btn-lg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!--Mailchimp-->
```

The CSS:

```
.btn-outline-white {
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px black;
    border-radius: 40px;
}
```

Can anyone explain what could be causing this, considering the actual files on my computer and the GitHub repository are identical? Thank you.

Comment: There is something in their css that is overriding your css.

Comment: If you inspect the element live on github pages, what does it show (css wise) for the element?. If may be getting overwritten. You can try adding some `!important` clauses to see if that helps

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Used the inspector and actually found that I still had MailChimp's stylesheet linked in my head tag ... certainly explains a lot.